# Replacing text in a word document with apache POI fails because Run Objects of Paragraph are splitted at placeholder

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI (Version 3.17) to replace some text in MS Word and Excel documents. The placeholder inside of the document has the following structure: [key].

When I replace the [key] value, all existing formatting options have to persist. The problem is, when a paragraph containing such a placeholder is found, the list of Run Objects is build like this:

1. ... [
2. key] ...

It is not possible to keep the placeholder in a single Run.
I could examine multiple runs but in this way it is a real mess to figure out the right style and the amount of runs, the placeholder spans.

Is it possible to force a Run to always contain the placeholder in its full length? All parts of the placeholder are formatted in the same way.

When does POI decide to create a new Run? I would understand, that POI splits the placeholder if it is formatted in different ways but there obviously are different criterias for POI to start a new Run.

Comment: "When does POI decide to create a new Run?" The `apache poi` starts a new run if the program has a command to do so - `paragraph.createRun()`. But in your case it is *not* `apache poi` which starts a new run, but `Word`. So `apache poi` has to deal with what `Word` has produced and it has no chance to "correct" it the way you want.